# selectize js autocomplete doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, selectize.js

Please see the following example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ejVB7/4/)  :

Although I can select the option from the dropdown, typing doesnt autocomplete.
I would expect that when you type B or A you should get the recommendation for banana, apple.
Only when of my items in the list is not an existing item it should ask me to add it...

var data = [ "banana", "apple", "orange" ];
var items = data.map(function(x) { return { item: x }; });

```
$('#input-tags').selectize({
    delimiter: ',',
    persist: false,
    maxItems: 1,
    create:true,
    options: items,
    labelField: "item",
    valueField: "item"
});
```

Any ideas?

Note the same scenario seems to be working with predefined values :
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zELuw/4/)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add a

```
searchField: "item"
```

to the selectize declaration

here's the fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wh6Nx/

to add items you need a

```
create: function(input) {
    return {
        value: input,
        text: input
    }
}
```

fiddle with both: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZrEu/

Comment: Further documentation can be found here: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md#data_searching

Comment: Spent longer than I liked figuring out why this wasn't working... Thanks.